# Hanging two bulb lamp

Tags: electrical, lighting

Replaced pull chain switch in hanging lamp.  After rehanging both bulbs came on but only one will turn off and on, the second bulb stays on constantly.   Do I need to reverse the switch wires or the wires from lamp to electric box?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring inside the lamp?

Comment: Is this a 4-position pull chain where you can turn on A, B or both?

Comment: The switch is just a simple on off pull switch(same as was original)

Comment: Sounds like you put one of the lamps on the hot side of the switch.